# filtering the joint which we want to draw

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing, kinect

i playing with kinect and i want to have control about drawing every part of the human body.
I make a combo box'es like :

- invisible left arm,
- invisible right arm,
  ...

and i've connected it with the drawbone method and its work. Now, I try to filtering the joints which lays on the invisible bones to make them invisible too, I have code like this :

```
             foreach (Joint joint in skeleton.Joints)
         {
             Brush drawBrush= null;


             if (joint.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Tracked)
             {
                 drawBrush = Brushes.Black;
             }
             else if (joint.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Inferred){
             drawBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.Blue);
             }
             if (drawBrush != null)
             {
                 drawingContext.DrawEllipse(drawBrush, null,       this.SkeletonPoint(joint.Position), 20, 20);
             }
         }
```

I've tryied with position

```
if (joint.Position == JointType.ShoulderLeft) { return; }
```

but error

I'm trying to compare it in some way but i get errors, becouse i' m acting like a blind kid :/

thx for any advices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing a Position to a JointType which has no sense. Try doing this:

```
if (joint.JointType == JointType.ShoulderLeft)
```

remember that position refers to the spatial position of the joint as said [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.joint.position.aspx)

whereas the JointType refers to the "anatomical name" of the tracked joint as said [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.joint.jointtype.aspx)